# How to retrieve a non-terminating xsl:message in MSXML6 and C++/Delphi?

Tags: c++, xml, delphi, xslt

I am using the MSXML 6.0 parser for XSL transformation and want to fetch `<xsl:message terminate="no">` [debug messages](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_message.asp). From what I found on the net this seems to be [possible in .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltmessageencounteredeventargs.message%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Is there a way to get the message output when using the COM interface (C++ or Delphi example code would be great)?

**Update:**

This is the code I use to do the XSL transformation (pretty straight forward):

```
uses ActiveX, {...} MSXML2_TLB;

function TransformMsXmlDocument( XmlDoc, XslDoc: iXmlDomDocument2 ) : UnicodeString;
var
   XslDoc2 : iXmlDomDocument;
   XslTemplate : iXslTemplate;
   XslProcessor : iXslProcessor;
begin
   XslDoc2 := CoFreeThreadedDomDocument60.Create();
   XslDoc2.Async := FALSE;
   XslDoc2.Load(XslDoc);

   XslTemplate := CoXslTemplate60.Create();
   XslTemplate.Stylesheet := XslDoc2;
   XslProcessor := XslTemplate.CreateProcessor();
   XslProcessor.Input := XmlDoc;

   XslProcessor.Transform();
   result := XslProcessor.Output;
end;
```

Comment: First of all, the .NET implementations of XSLT 1.0, `XslTransform` and `XslCompiledTransform`, are pure managed implementations and have no relation with the various MSXML versions. As for an example with MSXML 6 and C++, I don't have one, but perhaps the source code of Microsoft's `msxsl` command line tool has code doing that, so I would try looking into there https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21714.

Comment: Could you add to your q please the exact Delphi code (if any) you're using to do the transformation?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: I tested the `msxsl.exe` command-line tool but apparently it doesn't handle `<xsl:message terminate="no">` commands: Nothing is printed on the screen when I add them to the XSL. When using `terminate="yes"` the command terminates and the error string contains my message. I also had a quick look at the sources but couldn't find something relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt you can do this with MS XML 6.0.

Like you, I generated the MSXML2_Tlb.Pas import file and tested with code v. similar to yours.  The first problem is that the `OnReadyStateChange` and `OnDataAvailable` events of the Delphi wrapper components TDomDocument60 and
TFreeThreadedDomDocument60 are never called.

So, then I wrote a OleVariant wrapper for an event sink which connects at run-time to the DomDocument60 via its ConnectionPointContainer interface to get an IConnectionPoint and calling .Advise() on that.  I found that this event sink *is* called, four times, as the XML document loads, each time with a DispID of -609, which is the DispID of `onreadystatechange` (of XMLDOMDocumentEvents).  But a) the Params (PDispParams ) passed to my wrapper's Invoke are empty, and b) its Invoke is not called for `ondataavailable` nor anything else, in particular `ontransformnode` (whose DispID I don't know).

So it seems to me firstly that the events of the objects in MSXML2_Tlb aren't working properly and secondly that there is no obvious way of catching the `ontransformnode` event of the XML document being transformed.

Fwiw, the VB example on the page you linked,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xsl.xsltmessageencounteredeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

seems to imply that there's a way of getting at `XsltMessageEncounteredEventArgs` from VB, but I'm not familiar enough with importing the Net libraries into a Delphi project to know what I would need to import to be able to access it.  If someone could tell me that, I'd be happy to have a go.

Comment: OK, thanks for digging into it. I don't intend to convert my whole project from native to managed code (.NET) which would be the requirement for using the `XsltMessageEncounteredEventArgs` class.

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, I have made a bit more progress, but no solution yet.  I stumbled upon the "Important" note here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767521%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and have tried using MSXML3 instead of MSXML6.  At least with v.3, the ontransformnode event fires, but I haven't yet managed to get any useful information from the arguments passed to the event.  I'll update my answer if I get anywhere further.