# Generating a wrapper unit for a .Net Assembly

Tags: delphi, .net-assembly, delphi-10-seattle

On a Win 10 64-bit system, I'm trying to generate an import unit for the System.Xml NET Assembly into Delphi Seattle for a 32-bit project.  So far as I understand it, I'm supposed to go to 
`Component | Import Component`, select `Import .NET Assembly` and click the
`Next` button.

I'll describe what happens when I do in a moment, but I've checked whether System.Xml is on the GAC and it appears to be, according to GACUtil:

> Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.17929
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
>   CustomMarshalers, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>
> [...]
>
> System.Xml, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL
>
> [...]
>
> Number of items = 1991

However, when I click the `Next` button in `Import Component`,  all I see on the pop-up's
Registered Assemblies tab's listbox is the single entry "CustomMarshalers".  From there

a) Selecting `CustomMarshalers` and clicking `Next` (just to see what happens) takes me to the
`Component` tab and the `Class Name(s)` box is empty.

b) Instead of a), typing "system.xml" in the `Search` box filters out the `CustomMarshalers` entry leaving
`No items available.`

c) Instead of a), clicking the `Add` button, navigating to and selecting system.xml.dll in the .NetFramework\v4.0 folder
in the `Register .NET Assembly` pop-up and then clicking Open returns me to the `Registered Assemblies` tab
but does not add it to the list (I assume for the same reason, whatever it as, as prevents it being listed there in the first place, 
despite GACUtil reporting that it's registered).

So I can't complete the `Import Component Wizard` at all.  I assume I'm doing something wrong, but what, and how do I do it successfully?

Fwiw, I've tried running Seattle as administrator in case it makes a difference but it doesn't.

Comment: You need the classes that you are importing to be COM visible. Are they?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I don't know, how would I tell that, and how would I make it visible if it isn't already?

Comment: Read about `ComVisible` but you can't just enable that for arbitrary classes. Ultimately this is still COM so you have to do all the work that goes with that, and adhere to the rules.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I've had a look for ComVisible and there seems to be plenty of stuff in MSDN & elsewhere about how to make your own assembly ComVisible when you write it, but I haven't seen anything about about how to find out whether an existing assembly has it and, if it doesn't, what to do to change it,  Also if "this is still COM", these hoops seem a remarkably round the houses way of getting at it.

Comment: It's really not at all difficult: https://limbioliong.wordpress.com/2011/08/30/creating-a-com-server-using-c/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan.  Thanks, but using RegASM as per that article gives the same result as I got with TLBExp, i.e. an effectively empty .Tlb containing only a LibIID.  So I give up.

Comment: Well preusmably that's because that assembly doesn't attempt to implement a COM server.  You just cannot expect to turn arbitrary C# code into a COM server without doing some work.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I wasn't expecting anything.  This arose from trying to answer this q:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36396392/how-to-retrieve-a-non-terminating-xslmessage-in-msxml6-and-c-delphi.  I was wondering whether the .Net "solution" mentioned was somehow accessible from Delphi, seeing as the relevant event, ontransformnode, doesn't seem to get called in MSXML6.  But on reflection, I would not be at all surprised if, having somehow been able to use the assembly, it turned out that the event doesn't work properly from that either.

Comment: You could certainly wrap up those xslt classes with COM and expose them to Delphi. I'd be looking for a native solution though. The first comment to that Q is, in my view, all the answer that is needed.